# Authentication - VS 2017 15.3; ASP.Net Core 2.0; Angular

Tags: angular, visual-studio-2017

When selecting the Angular template VS 15.3 gives no other authentication choice other than "no authentication". I will be referencing Angular Components in Views. How do I get authentication functionality into the app? TIA

Comment: This seems to be feature request, I am sure there should be a support page for Visual Studio, you may request this feature there, Cheers!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an ASP.NET Core 2.0 non-SPA project with authentication. You can then add the classes and other functionality related to server-side authentication to your SPA project.

Additionally see the following documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/identity-2x
- AND - 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/